# Cordova verify app is asleep when not active

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having test users say that my app is taking too much battery life on their android devices. I'm testing on a tablet (nexus 7) and in the Settings > App info > Permissions I see `prevent tablet from sleeping`.

So does this mean that my app *is* keeping the device from sleeping or just that it can?

Regardless I need to find out how to make sure my app is not doing any background processing. How can I test this?

Note:
I'm using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` and I'm concerned it's still running in the background, taking up more than needed resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is the `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition`.

You will want to make use of the device events to handle stopping and starting this when the app is paused and resumed.

Here is a quick sudo example:

Define a global for your watcher `var watcher;`

Add listeners for `pause` and `resume`:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

When you start your watcher assign it to the global:

```
watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Create `onPause` and clear the watcher:

```
function onPause() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcher);
}
```

If you want it to start again when the app is resumed, create `onResume` and start it again:

```
function onResume() {
    watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

Comment: Good assumption, unfortunately I had done that already. I did notice that the watch was being triggered sometimes once a second so what I did along the lines of your answer was took out watching and moved to a manual approach but on a 30 second interval, still stopping / starting on pause / resume.